# PyQt 100% width window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

So I am trying to create a window (QDialog) with a width of a 100% (of the screen) and a height of a fixed value, eg. 60px.

I tried to achieve this by setting the maximumSize's height property to 60px, leaving the width to whatever it was. (16777215)
I also set the horizontal sizePolicy to Maximum, and the vertical to Fixed, with stretch values of 1 and 0 respectively.

[image: Here are the properties I tried to modify]
[image: Here is the result]

As you can see in the picture above, the dialog appears centered, but not stretched at all horizontally.

The code is pretty simple as seen below, its just a frameless QDialog:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, uic
import sys
import os

class FMenu(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FMenu, self).__init__()
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        self.ui = uic.loadUi('./ui/ui_searchbar.ui', self)
        self.ui.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.ui.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = FMenu()
app.exec_()
```

The ui file I created with QtDesigner is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>SearchBar</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="SearchBar">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>60</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>1</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>16777215</width>
    <height>60</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background: #2b2b2b;</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget" native="true">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>801</width>
     <height>61</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_searchBar">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>781</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
      <horstretch>1</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="maximumSize">
     <size>
      <width>16777215</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Times New Roman</family>
      <pointsize>22</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background: #3b3b3b;
color: #fff;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="placeholderText">
     <string>Write here...</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Edited the question, added the python code and the ui file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maximumSize only indicates the maximum size it can take, it does not indicate that the widget will be stretched. In that case it is better to use a layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>SearchBar</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="SearchBar">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>870</width>
    <height>60</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>1</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>16777215</width>
    <height>60</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background: #2b2b2b;</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget" native="true">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
      <property name="leftMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="topMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="rightMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="bottomMargin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_searchBar">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>1</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>16777215</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <family>Times New Roman</family>
          <pointsize>22</pointsize>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background: #3b3b3b;
color: #fff;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="placeholderText">
         <string>Write here...</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

If you want to occupy the entire screen, then you have to calculate the size of the screen:

```py
window.setFixedWidth(app.primaryScreen().availableSize().width())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Tried this, and got the same result for some reason. Did this work for you?

Comment: @ÁdámMaul Hmm, maybe I didn't understand your question. What do you call window? You mean the screen? I understand that you want that if the user changes the width of the window (not the screen) then the QLineEdit must also do it and that is what my code does: https://i.imgur.com/Np9DfGi.png

Comment: Then I think I just suck at explaining things, sorry, I will try again. Your code helps, because I indeed want the lineedit to be full width of the window, but I also want the window to fill the full width of the screen. My main concern was the window filling the screen horizontally. Like a top bar, or like the start menu does on windows for example.

Comment: @ÁdámMaul then add `window.setFixedWidth(app.primaryScreen().availableSize().width())` and rewrite your post.